# ComboBox's Text property has value of last selection, not current selection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a Label `LabelMessage` and a ComboBox `ComboBoxSelection` on a WPF page. Here is the XAML:

```
<Label Name="LabelMessage" Content="" Margin="0,20" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
<ComboBox x:Name="ComboBoxSelection" SelectionChanged="OnComboBoxSelectionChanged" Height="20" Margin="112,10,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsEnabled="True" >
    <ComboBoxItem Content="North" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="South" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="East" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="West" />
</ComboBox>
```

And here is the C#:

```
private void OnComboBoxSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    LabelMessage.Content = ComboBoxSelection.Text;
}
```

The label shows the *previous* content of the ComboBox, not the current selection. Thank is, if I select `North` then `East`, the Label will show `North`. If I then select `South` the label will show `East`.

What might cause this, and how should I fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: just use `ComboBoxSelection.SelectedItem.ToString();`

Comment: Thanks. I also had to remove some filler string, but that did the trick. Go ahead and post your comment as an answer so that I might accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use something along the lines of: `ComboBoxSelection.SelectedItem.ToString();`

Answer (score 0):

The solution:

```
LabelMessage.Content = ComboBoxSelection.SelectedItem.ToString().Replace("System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem: ", "");
```